# Repeat rows from dataframe based in list of index

Tags: python, pandas, list, indexing, repeat

What I am looking for is repeat rows from my dataframe based on list of index.

I already got this using for loop, but I am trying to improve my code because I have a large dataframe and the method I used is taking so time.

Here is one example that I am trying to do.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['Brazil','UK','Canada','USA'],'value': [5,3,2,7]})
list_index = [2,0,3,0,1,2,3,3,0,2,2]
```

My df

```py
  country  value
0  Brazil      5
1      UK      3
2  Canada      2
3     USA      7
```

To get my result, I implemented this

```py
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'country': [], 'value':[]})
for i in list_index:
    new_df = new_df.append(df.iloc[i])
```

Output new_df

```py
  country  value
2  Canada    2.0
0  Brazil    5.0
3     USA    7.0
0  Brazil    5.0
1      UK    3.0
2  Canada    2.0
3     USA    7.0
3     USA    7.0
0  Brazil    5.0
2  Canada    2.0
2  Canada    2.0
```

Is there a better way to achieve my goal without using for loop? `apply()` function would be great.

Comment: `df.loc[list_index]`?

Comment: Or `print (df.reindex(list_index))`

Comment: Thanks a lot, both method worked very well. But ```df.loc[list_index]``` is taking less time than ```df.reindex(list_index)```.